# Removing all characters after specific character

Tags: javascript

I know this is a simple task, but my Javascript knowledge is (very) limited and I can't seem to get this to work. I've researched it thoroughly and have read through several similar questions here before posting, but still no luck. I'm trying to remove all characters after the comma within a particular div. My poor understanding of Javascript (and programming in general) is certainly limiting me here.

```js
var s = document.getelementsbyclassname('menu-staff');
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(','));
document.write(s);
```

```html
<div class="menu-staff">Value One, Value Two, Value Three, Value Four</div>
```

I can get this to work for a static string stored in the variable, so I know the Javascript function works, it must simply be a problem with targeting the div by class, right? Thanks for bearing with a newbie. I fully expect this to be flagged as a duplicate and removed in a matter of hours, but hopefully someone will be kind enough to guide an ignorant designer towards the light. :)

Comment: There's no way that javascript works, first of all, **case matters**, it's `getElementsByClassName`, and it returns a nodeList, not a string?

Comment: Try: get**E**lements**B**y**C**lass**N**ame

Comment: #1 thing you *have* to do when you're coding in browser JavaScript: [keep the browser's error console open](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). You're just flailing in the dark if you don't see the error messages.

Comment: Press F12 and click on the little red cross.

Comment: @this.lau_ Why the little red cross? :P

Comment: Converted your code into a snippet. The StackSnippet plugin actually has a console. Click the button to SEE your error. It is plain as daylight. :) -> *"message": "Uncaught TypeError: document.getelementsbyclassname is not a function",*

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I knew I'd get destroyed in an area outside my expertise, but a little pain helps the growth process, so thank you once again. I apologize; I had copied an iteration (with incorrect case syntax) that I'd adjusted since getting the function to work (attempting to get it working) without double checking. I'll keep that in mind as I continue. And I will certainly keep the console in mind for debugging. I was trying to get it to work in jsfiddle... And thanks for the note about snippets. I'll use that next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your string into parts and then just output the first one.

```js
var str = document.querySelector('.menu-staff').innerHTML;
console.log(str);
var parts = str.split(',');
document.write(parts[0]); //Pssst... You shouldn't use document.write. Manipulate the DOm instead.
```

```html
<div class="menu-staff">Value One, Value Two, Value Three, Value Four</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Moob. Again, I apologize for my ignorance. Regarding your note, about not using `document.write`, can you offer an alternative way of outputting this correctly? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could split pieces of your string separated by a comma into an array and just keep the first element :

```
var s = "bonjour, et bienvenu";
console.log(s.split(",")[0]); // bonjour
```

Comment: This errors. I think you mean `console.log(s.split(",")[0]);` (no dot)

Comment: @Moob Yes shame and me and thanks for your hawkeyes

Comment: The OP's problem is not getting the correct output, but targeting the HTML element. *"I can get this to work for a static string stored in the variable"*

Comment: Hey your code is wrong, because document.getElementsByClassName would return an array, you might considering changing your code to this var s = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-staff');
 var input=s[0].innerHTML;
input = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(','));
document.write(input);